# Looking up encrypted keys in a key value store

Tags: encryption, redis, hashmap

I have a requirement to encrypt the keys in a redis cache. Redis is a key - value store. 
I can encrypt the keys  using a standard encryption algorithm while inserting into the cache fine. But how do I do a lookup afterwards?

So say, I want to lookup a key "234" .i encrypt "234" using the same algorithm but the encrypted value will be different every time. So it won't match the encrypted value that's in the cache.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse Encryption keys with the key used to look up in your "Key / value store". Encryption keys are used for encrypting stuff, whereas the "Key" in your "Key / value store" is just a name to index your values by.

In your case you Encryption key would be encrypted and then goes into the Value part. Your index would still work, as this is not encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption result would not be different. Encryption is a two-way mapping between plaintext and ciphertext, given the cryptographic key. 
The result of encryption may differ if you’re using a block cipher with random padding, but it’s unlikely. Even if that’s the case, you can just change the padding mode or the encryption algorithm.

So if you want to lookup key "hello" - just encrypt it and look up encrypted string in redis.